# How to get the match for the following use cases from this regex pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have the Regex to match the following patterns,

Link to the Use case: https://regex101.com/r/wnp1k4/1

How can i get the match for the same by modifying the Regex? please help.

```
(?:^|(?<=[\D;a-zA-Z(),.:;?!"'`>]))(?!000|666|9)(?<![Oo][Rr][Dd][Ee][Rr].)(?<![Oo][Rr][Dd][Ee][Rr]..)(?<![Oo][Rr][Dd][Ee][Rr]...)(?<![Oo][Rr][Dd][Ee][Rr].[Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr].)(?<![Oo][Rr][Dd][Ee][Rr].[Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]..)(?<![Oo][Rr][Dd][Ee][Rr].[Nn][Uu][Mm][Bb][Ee][Rr]...)(?<![Xx])\d{3}[ -.=\n\r]{0,10}(?!00)\d{2}[ -.=\n\r]{0,10}(?!0000)\d{4}(?:$|(?=[\Da-zA-Z(),.:;?!"'`<= ]))
```

Order numbers should not get detected if 'X or x' precedes the number. so this is working fine.

x123456789

X123456789

x123-456-789

X123-456-789

123-456-789

Need to modify the regex pattern to get the match for the list of ordernumbers written like below...along with the word (order number) should be case insensitive.

ordernumber123-456-789

order number123-456789

order number 123456789

123-456789

123456789

ordernumber-123456787

ordernumber - 123456789

ordernumber #123456789

ordernumber *anysplcharacter*123456789

Comment: Will You explain what exactly you want to match using  the regex

Comment: @anubhava i have given it in this link https://regex101.com/r/wnp1k4/1

Comment: @anubhava apologies. my bad, i've given it in the question. Thanks :)

Comment: From the given sample text what are your expected matches and what substrings should be captured?

Comment: @anubhava, we need to detect a 9 digit order number written in the above form.. The list of Above 9 use cases. If there is a string 'order number' followed with 9 digit number, it should be matched. That order number should get detected if its of any case and if it includes any special character inbetween like 
'order-number - 987123456'

above are the few example use cases i've given.

Comment: @anubhava, in the given link i can see the Regex pattern matching the numbers which are followed after the string orderNumbers. But it is not matching the 9 digit number if given alone. It should match as well. Also, i'm wondering if the String orderNumber will also can get a match? Or is it too complex to implement it?

Comment: @Kameysh: May be this one: https://regex101.com/r/wnp1k4/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex:

```sh
(?<!\d)(?!000|666|9)(order\W?number)?\W*(?<!x)\d{3}[ .=-]{0,10}(?!000)\d{3}[ .=-]{0,10}(?!000)\d{3}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wnp1k4/7)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\d)`: Make sure that previous character is not a digit
- `(?!000|666|9)`: Make sure that we don't have `000` or `666` or `9` at the next position
- `(order\W?number)?`: Match `order` and `number` optionally separated with a non-word character
- `\W*`: Match 0 or more non-word characters
- `(?<!x)`: Make sure previous character is not `x`
- `\d{3}`: Match 3 digits
- `[ .=-]{0,10}`: Match 0 to 10 instances of given separators
- `(?!000)`: Make sure we don't have `000` at next position
- `\d{3}`: Match 3 digits
- `[ .=-]{0,10}`: Match 0 to 10 instances of given separators
- `(?!000)`: Make sure we don't have `000` at next position
- `\d{3}`: Match 3 digits

Comment: this is amazing. It matched all the usecases as expected. But a small doubt, why does it matches the Special characters too? The regex should not match the special characters, but the 9 digit numbers put in front or back of it should get matched... along with ordernumber or without ordernumber string.

Comment: @Kameysh ... The requirements make it necessary to come up with a regex which is forced to capture both a valid version of an optional key like `'order number'` and a valid version of the oder number value. And due to the optional character sequence which is allowed to exist in between the other two (except of the number value preceding `'x'`) such a sequence has to be part of a matching regex as well.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, Thank you so much for the explanation. I got it. Thanks for your tremendous help. i'm humbled.

Comment: @anubhava,  Is it possible to modify the regex to include this use case to get a match for the 9 digit number if it's written with spaces? "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

Comment: @Kameysh: That will totally break the regex logic currently in place. I suggest you remove spaces first using `str.replaceAll("\\s+(?=\\d)", "");` and then run this regex

Answer (score 1):

[`/((?<key>order\s*number).*)?(?<!x)(?<value>\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{6}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})/gim`](https://regex101.com/r/wnp1k4/6)

```js
const multilineSample = `x123456789
X123456789
x123-456-789
X123-456-789

123-456-789

ordernumber123-456-789
order number123-456789
order number 123456789

123-456789
123456789

ordernumber-x123456787

ordernumber-123456787
ordernumber - 123456789
ordernumber #123456789
ordernumber *anysplcharacter*123456789
ordernumber !@#$%^&123456789

ordernumber !@#$%^&x123456789`;

const regXOrderNumber =
  // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/wnp1k4/6]
  /((?<key>order\s*number).*)?(?<!x)(?<value>\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{6}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})/gim;

console.log(
  'all results each with its mapped named capture group ...',
  Array.from(
    multilineSample.matchAll(regXOrderNumber)
  )
  .map(({ groups }) => groups)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'm amazed with your solution. You have given a Regex where i can remove that order number if i want, and add it back and still it matches all the 9 digit numbers. Thank you so much.

Comment: @peterseilger, Is it possible to modify the regex to get a match for the 9 digit number if it's written with spaces? "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

Comment: @Kameysh ... I don't know. But I also would never try. Nobody could possibly read/understand/maintain such a regex. Sanitizing the string with a replace task like [`'1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.replace(/\s+(?=\d)/g, '')`](https://regex101.com/r/wnp1k4/8) before the order number matching takes place is the recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
^([^x]|(order\s?number\s?)(\s?[-|#]?\s?))(anysplcharacter)?([\d-]+)$
```

Is there another case?

Comment: Hey this is a good one. But the regex pattern did not match this 'ordernumber!@#$%^&123456789' And in the regex, how should i place the special characters?  I don't get it.

Comment: @Kameysh: Just fyi this will also match any number of digits not just 9. So `123-45678911` or just `----` will also be a valid match.