# How to get the match for the following use cases with the regex pattern that i have?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi Have the Following Regex written.

```
(?<!x)(\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{6}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})
```

I want to modify the existing Regex so that the below use cases can get a match, right now only few are matching.

Note:

1. 9 digit Order numbers should not get detected if 'X or x' precedes the
   number and that part is working fine.
2. 9 digit numbers, Non-numeric characters or whitespaces (up to 3) in between numbers should also get matched.

Use cases:

[This is a list of Use cases that needs to be Matched](https://regex101.com/r/iFiwx5/1)

https://regex101.com/r/iFiwx5/1

Example:
These are the use cases that needs to be matched with the regex.

1. 123 45 6789
2. 123-45-6789
3. 123-45-6789
4. 123 – 45 – 6789
5. 123.45.6789
6. 123_45_6789
7. 123 456 789
8. 123-456-789
9. 123 – 456 – 789
10. 123.456.789
11. 123_456_789
12. 1234 56 789
13. 1234-56-789
14. 1234 – 56 – 789
15. 1234.56.789
16. 1234_56_789
17. 12 345 6789
18. 12-345-6789
19. 12 – 345 – 6789
20. 12.345.6789
21. 12_345_6789

Any help on this would be really good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand problem correct, you may use this regex:

```sh
(?<!x)(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})\d{2,}[._ –-]*\d{2,}[._ –-]*\d{2,}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iFiwx5/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!x)` Make sure digits are not preceded with letter `x`
- `(?=(?:[._ –-]*\d){9})` ensures presence of at least 9 digits separated with 0 or more allowed delimiters
- `[._ –-]*`: allows for presence of 0 or more of these delimiters every 2 or more digits

Comment: That is exactly the solution i was looking for. You are very good at this, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I may have something extra with the above, should i make a new question? or can i paste it here?

Comment: I'm not able to post a new question as it says "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account". However, the add-on condition to the above question is, 

The logic is all correct, it matches the use cases, but when the following rules comes in, then the Regex should not match the numbers.. The rules are as follows,

The order numbers should not get matched,


 If the number beginning with the number “9”,
If the number “666” in positions 1 – 3,
If the number “000” in positions 1 – 3,
If the number “00” in positions 4 – 5,
if the number “0000” in positions 6 – 9

Comment: Sorry but those would not be a minor tweak as that would require many changes. I had posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71203269/548225) that takes care of some of these rules.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. But the other solution does not match with all the use cases from this question. since i'm not able to post a new question I don't know what to do.

Comment: I think they will let you post a new question in a day. Many of the rules you mentioned are covered in the previous question. You can use that as example and try to build on that